# User input from numbered list and returns the list

Tags: python, list, input

I have this program where it reads and displays a list, separated by commas. I also have each list numbered. I ask the user to select a number from that list. From the number they chose, I'm trying to return the actual list value that goes with it. I am having trouble returning just the list value for some reason.

So if I were to choose '2' (integer) as my input, it should return Customers.

Here is my code so far:

```
list1 = ['ID', 'Customers', 'Employees', 'Orders']

def display(list1):
    counter = 0
    record = []
    for tables in list1:
        counter += 1
        record.append(tables)
        print("%s. %s" % (counter, tables))
    return record

def get_list(record):
    print("\nPick a number:")
    choose = input()
    choose = int(choose)

    x = []
    if choose in record:
        x.append(record)
        print(x)

record = display(list1)
get_list(record)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `choose` index to select the item from `record` key via
  `print(record[int(choose)-1])`

So the code will change to

```
list1 = ['ID', 'Customers', 'Employees', 'Orders']

def display(list1):
    counter = 0
    record = []
    for tables in list1:
        counter += 1
        record.append(tables)
        print("%s. %s" % (counter, tables))
    return record

def get_list(record):
    print("\nPick a number:")
    choose = input()
    choice = int(choose)-1
    print(record[choice])

record = display(list1)
get_list(record)
```

You can also simplify your code as follows

```
li = ['ID', 'Customers', 'Employees', 'Orders']

def display(li):
    #Iterate through the list using enumerate and print
    for idx, tables in enumerate(li):
        print("%s. %s" % (idx+1, tables))

def get_list(li):
    choose = int(input("\nPick a number:"))-1
    #If choose is not a valid index in list, print error and return empty string
    if choose < 0 or choose > (len(li)-1):
        print('Invalid Choice')
        return ''
    #Else return chosen string
    return li[choose]

display(li)
print(get_list(li))
```

The output will then be

```
1. ID
2. Customers
3. Employees
4. Orders

Pick a number:
3
Employees

1. ID
2. Customers
3. Employees
4. Orders

Pick a number:0
Invalid Choice
```

Comment: so what will the return type be for get_list if I were to use that return type for another function?

Comment: You can just `return record[choice]` if you want to return the chosen item from the list

Comment: so on the main file I can just do this choice = get_list(record)?

Comment: That is right, I also updated a much simplified version of the code as well in the answer!

Comment: This is great thank u! Enumerate was my first approach

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dict` instead.

```py
list1 = ['ID', 'Customers', 'Employees', 'Orders']

def display(list1):
    counter = 0
    record = {}
    for tables in list1:
        counter += 1
        record[counter] = tables
        print("%s. %s" % (counter, tables))
    return record

def get_list(record):
    print("\nPick a number:")
    choose = input()
    choose = int(choose)

    if choose in record:        
        print(record[choose])

record = display(list1)
get_list(record)
```

Output:

```
1. ID
2. Customers
3. Employees
4. Orders

Pick a number:
2
Customers
```

And your `record` variable will look like:

```
{1: 'ID', 2: 'Customers', 3: 'Employees', 4: 'Orders'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply access the list index entered by the user

```
list1 = ['ID', 'Customers', 'Employees', 'Orders']

def display(list1):
    counter = 0
    record = []
    for tables in list1:
        counter += 1
        record.append(tables)
        print("%s. %s" % (counter, tables))
    return record

def get_list(record):
    print("\nPick a number:")
    choose = input()
    choose = int(choose)
    print(record[choose-1])

record = display(list1)
get_list(record)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by single function see below code:

```
list1 = ['ID', 'Customers', 'Employees', 'Orders']



def display(list1):
    maxnum = len(list1)
    print("\nPick a number from 1 to %s:"%(maxnum+1))
    choose = input()
    choose = int(choose)
    if choose > maxnum:
        print("enter number less than %s"%(maxnum+1))
        return
    choose = choose-1

    print (list1[choose])

display(list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Python, List indexing started with 0, for getting required output you need to subtract input value by 1.**

```
    list1 = ['ID', 'Customers', 'Employees', 'Orders']

    def display(list1):
        counter = 0
        record = []
        for tables in list1:
            counter += 1
            record.append(tables)
            print("%s. %s" % (counter, tables))
        return record

    def get_list(record):
        print("\nPick a number:")
        choose = input()
        choose = int(choose)
        print(record[choose - 1])    

    record = display(list1)
    get_list(record)
```

**Output**

1. ID
2. Customers
3. Employees
4. Orders

Pick a number:
2
Customers